# CentOS 7: dhclient.conf prepend domain-name-servers not working

Tags: centos, networkmanager, dhclient

I need to prepend my `/etc/resolv.conf` with an entry. My interface is enp0s3.   So I created `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enp0s3.conf` and added the line:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.2
```

When I restart the CentOS VM, the NetworkManager automatically creates this file: `/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-enp0s3.conf`

When I cat that I can see that my dhclient-enp0s3.conf file in /etc/dhcp IS being read properly:

```
[root@localhost network-scripts]# cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-enp0s3.conf
# Created by NetworkManager
# Merged from /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enp0s3.conf

prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.2

option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;
option ms-classless-static-routes code 249 = array of unsigned integer 8;
option wpad code 252 = string;

also request rfc3442-classless-static-routes;
also request ms-classless-static-routes;
also request static-routes;
also request wpad;
also request ntp-servers;
```

However, when I cat `/etc/resolv.conf`, the prepended nameserver doesn't appear anywhere.   I also ran `dig` just to test if my internal hostnames would resolve properly, but they don't.

Since the NetworkManager config appears to be generated, where do I go from here?

Comment: Thank you for the edits @cas.  Thanks to your edit, I looked at the markup and learned how to do some of it properly!  (Now if I knew how to reference your username properly.  :)

Comment: for code and command/file names etc use either backticks or the `{}` icon in the editor (the latter especially for multi-line blocks of code - or just indent each line by four spaces).   `@cas` works.   sorry i can't help with your actual question - my attitude to networkmanager, resolvconf and other things that mess with my hand-crafted configs is `apt-get purge` with the `--nuke-from-orbit-its-the-only-way-to-be-sure` option :).

Comment: hahaha ... yeah for an old skool guy like me its painful to learn the new way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Config statements in dhclient.conf (and other dhcp config files) must be terminated with a semicolon.

So `prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.2;` should do the trick.

Comment: Bingo!   This indeed did the trick.

Comment: Can you do the following? ```prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;```. A simple yes or no will do for me! :)

Comment: If you have multiple ips, you can add multiple "prepend domain-name-servers"  lines